# why does setting different scaleX and scaleY for textfield distorts the text?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i have a textField wherein i uses embedded fonts, the problem is when i change its size and i do not set the SAME scaleX and scaleY value, it seems to compress the letters inside it when i make it smaller, and stretch the text when i make it bigger...

i tried using width and height values (instead of scaleX and scaleY but its the same result)... it seems that the embedded fonts are maintaining some kind of aspect ratio or whatever, and again this only happens when embedFonts is set to true

Comment: so you're not scaling the width and height of a vector display object proportionally and you want to know why it's not maintaining a proportionate scale?

Comment: i think i'm misunderstanding what your trying to do.  if you change the font size the textField should scale automatically.  can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution for maintaining a ratio is to use width/height and scaleX/Y together:

```
textField.width = 250;
textField.scaleY = textField.scaleX;
```

Comment: as confirmed in other forums, it seems that this is a normal behavior of embedded fonts but then again it seems that the only solution is really to adjust the font size and not the textfield size so that the font will not get stretched or compressed.... regarding @Corey's answer, i'm gonna have to try that one out, but actually i've already tried setting both scaleX and scaleY to 1 then setting the width and the result is it is still stretched or compressed... though i haven't tried setting the width first before the scale although i think the scale directly affects the width as well

Comment: You must make sure that scaleX and scaleY are always the same, otherwise you will experience distortion.  In your comment you set them both to 1 (good), then you only alter width, which will have no effect on the scaleY property.

Answer (score 0):

//Why don't you use "device fonts"?

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "benny";
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(300, 300);
myBitmapData.draw(tf);
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
this.addChild(bmp);
bmp.width = bmp.height = 1200;

bmp.x = stage.stageWidth/4;
bmp.y = stage.stageHeight/4;
```

Comment: we need to handle device + embedded fonts

Comment: I have added some code. Check with this. Perhaps helpful for u.